# c++ 2 constructors and a destructor in a class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

This is correct code from a classmate the professor bragged about and I cant understand why it requires a double constructor i originally only had the first function and couldnt figure out it required two which lagged my progress as a professional

```
class Studentrecords
{
private:

    struct student
    {
        string name;
        string address;
        int ID;
        double gpa;
    };

    student *stackArray;
    int stackSize;
    int top;

public:
    Studentrecords();
    Studentrecords(int size);
    ~Studentrecords();
    void push(string name, string address, int id, double gpa);
    void pop();
    bool isFull() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void display();
};

Studentrecords::Studentrecords(int size)
{
    stackArray = new student[size];
    top = 0;
}

Studentrecords::Studentrecords()
{
    stackSize = 25;
    stackArray = new student[stackSize];
    top = 0;
}

Studentrecords::~Studentrecords()
{
    delete [] stackArray;
}
```

Comment: Well, that's just buggy.  Initializing from an `int` never initializes the `stackSize` member, there's no copy/move constructor, no copy/move assignment operator, and it allows implicit conversions from `int` to `Studentrecords`.

Comment: why is stackSize not initialized ?.. i see stacksize = 25 could work?

Comment: That line isn't in `Studentrecords::Studentrecords(int size)` anywhere

Comment: For the record this code is ****ing awful. The stack should be implemented elsewhere in an abstract way and inherited. The stack should then handle the position (top) instead of polluting the StudentRecord class with it. And hard-coding stackSize = 25 in the default constructor just makes me want to throw up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't *require* two constructors, that's just how the class is defined. That way, you can create an object in two ways:

```
Studentrecords s(15);
```

which will create a `Studentrecords` object of size 15, or

```
Studentrecords s;
```

which will call the default constructor, and create an object of type `Studentrecords` and size 25.

I must note that this is bad code though:

- The default `Studentrecords()` constructor can be replaced with `Studentrecords(int size = 25)` to avoid code duplication.
- no use of initializer lists
- you're managing memory in the class, which means you'd need a copy constructor and copy assignment operator
- finally, you're using a C-style array instead of a `std::vector`.

Comment: Also maybe mention that one constructor never initializes `stackSize`?

Answer (score 4):

The second constructor allows you to initialize a `StudentRecords` to a given size. This is convenient, but not strictly necessary. Unfortunately, is also allows an implicit conversion from int to `StudentRecords`, which you can disable by making it `explicit`.

```
explicit Studentrecords(int size);
```

That will prevent nonsense such as

```
StudentRecords s = 4*5;
```

A more important fact is that your class deals with dynamically allocated resources, so you must follow the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) and provide a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator, besides the destructor that you have already provided.

Comment: @DavidSalazar that is supposed to show a code mistake, which would compile and do something unless you declare the constructor explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't require two constructors. A single constructor with a default argument is better. And the first constructor is broken, since it fails to set `stackSize`.